# Magento2 EE - Multi Language - CMS Page does not translated first time

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

I'm working on Magento Commerce cloud project which having two store views(English & Arabic)

While I'm trying to switch from English store view to Arabic store view from particular CMS page. It's not reflecting with translation. But it is showing applicable content while doing hard refresh.
As I marked that it is happening only on staging instance where fastly cache has been Activated.

Does fastly supporting for cms pages with multi-store view or not?

I'm unable to reproduce this issue into development instance even into private browser.

Comment: Hi @Ravi Dudhara, could you please check in private window. I think there is a browser cache issue.

Comment: @balu, Yes I was tested into the private window